# Why does my answer show upvotes but not reputation changes?

Tags: support, reputation

I answered a question here: [How to have getElementbyId different than Null after page loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608326/how-to-have-getelementbyid-different-than-null-after-page-loaded/60608379#60608379)

In my activity page, my answer to this question shows 2 upvotes without +10 reputation (These are also missing from my net reputation)

Could anyone assist or explain why this is so?

[image]

Comment: Maybe because you hit the daily rating limit (200 reputation per day, excluding from accepted answers).

Comment: Oh I see, so in such cases are these points added the next day? Or are they lost forever?

Comment: They are lost forever.

Comment: If you manage this feat often enough, you can earn badges: the [mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard), [epic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic), and [legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) badges. Fun fact: even though there is no rep on Meta, you can still earn those badges; [12 people have earned the Legendary badge on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary), for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and I could have guessed you were the first to earn it ...